# Composing multiple Essential matrices

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have computed the Essential matrices between `Frame [a,b], [b,c] and [c,d]`. I have now `E_ab`, `E_bc` and `E_cd`. Is it possible to compute `E_ad` directly without matching? I am thinking of sth like 3D transformation composing where:

```
T04 = T01 * T12 * T23 * T34
```

The solution that I found is to decompose each one it into R|T and construct T_4*4 from R|T and then use the previouse notation of composing T matrices and then convert the final R|T to E. However, I was wondering if there is a direct way without decomposing for two reasons:

- Decomposing and re composing (at least in OpenCV) changes the essential matrix a bit
- Performance sake

So, How can I combine two (or more) essential matrices directly?

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to achieve by computing those Essentials? If performance is  a real issue here then it's usually preferable to avoid computing consecutive Essential matrices. For example, for a lot of applications, it would be preferable to compute `E_ab` and then compute [R_bc, T_bc] via *e.g.* PnP, and recover the Essential matrix if needed (which is trivial and unlkike the inverse problem, doesn't require decompositions).

Comment: Ultimate goal is Bundle Adjustment on the Essential Matrices directly instead of on RT. I am using Single Calibrated Camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering the original question, I think it might be important to discuss this point from your comment:

> Ultimate goal is Bundle Adjustment on the Essential Matrices directly instead of on RT. I am using Single Calibrated Camera

It might be that I'm missing critical details about your project, but there seems to be a few issues with that method:

1. **Minimal representation.** Usually, it's better (for both performance and accuracy reasons) to use minimal parametrisations in your estimations. The Essential matrix has six degrees of freedom (which can be seen from its decomposition as `[T]_xR`). If you estimate your Essential directly, you're optimizing eight parameters instead of six.
2. **Less constrained problem.** The Essential matrix imposes coplanarity constraints and doesn't penalize some wrong configurations that would be penalized by reprojection errors that are used in usual bundle adjustment. If you consider two cameras `C_1` and `C_2` such that a point `X_2` expressed in `C_2` can be expressed in `C_1` via `RX_2+T`, and that we denote the corresponding point in `C_1` as `X_1`, then the constraint `X_1.transpose()*E*X_2=0` imposes that the three vectors `T, X_1` and `RX_2+T` remain coplanar. So, the point `X_2` is free to move as long as it reprojects to the epiploar line, even if its ray diverges from `X_1`:

   [image]

   As you can see in the figure, the red and green points would respect the Essential matrix constraint, however they would have different reprojection errors.
3. **Time complexity.** Computing Essentials is really slow compared to alternatives, and so is the recovery of rotation and translations from Essentials, compared to the inverse problem.

---

Now to come back to the initial problem from the question, if you consider the three cameras `C_1, C_2, C_3` and respectively denote their poses as `Identity, R_1, R_2`, and note the Essentials between `C_1` and `C_2` as `E_1` and the one between `C_2` and `C_3` as `E_2`, then you can easily see that the Essential from `C_3` to `C_1`, that I'll note `E_3`, will be given by

```
E_3=[R_1T_2+T_1]_x R_1R_2
```

which with a little bit of reorganization leads to

```
E_3=R_1E_2 + E_1R_2
```

This relation which establishes the link between the three Essential matrices seems to indicate that you still will need to extract `R_1` and `R_2` from `E_1` and `E_2`.

**Edit:** I derived the relationship above like this: assume `y` is a `3x1` vector, then

```
E_3y = [R_1T_2+T_1]_x R_1R_2y
     = (R_1T_2+T_1) x (R_1R_2y)
     = R_1T_2 x R_1R_2y + T_1 x R_1R_2y #for the next line, note that crossproduct is invariant under rotation
     = R_1(T_2 x R_2 y) + T_1 x R_1R_2 y
     = R_1[T_2]_x R_2 y + [T_1]x_x R_1 R_2 y
     = R_1 E_2 y + E_1 R_2 y
     = (R_1E_2 + E_1R_2) y
```

Since this holds for any arbitrary `y`, this means that `E_3=R_1E_2+E_1R_2`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ash! Actually, your first observation is much appreciated and I ended up trying to optimize the six parameters (3 angles + 3 translations). Thanks for pointing out the the essential matrices relation. May you please guide me to the reference you find that relation (if it was not drafted by you)? Thanks again!

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Glad it helped! I've added the derivation of the relation to the answer, let me know if you find any mistakes.